Implementing User Authentication with NextAuth.js in Next.js 14 and Node.js/Express API
I'm building an application with Next.js 14 for the frontend and Node.js with Express for the backend (REST API). I want to implement user authentication using NextAuth.js. I've attached a screenshot that roughly depicts the desired authentication flow:
I want to do this
My goal is to achieve the following authentication flow:

User logs in through a form on the Next.js frontend.
NextAuth.js handles the authentication process (e.g., email/password, social logins).
If successful, a token is generated and sent to the frontend.
Subsequent API calls from the frontend to my Node.js API will include the NextAuth.js token in the request header.
My Node.js API will verify the token's validity using NextAuth.js middleware or a similar approach.
If the token is valid, the API grants access and responds with the requested data.

My question is:

Is my understanding of the approach using NextAuth.js correct?
Should I implement NextAuth.js in my Next.js project to achieve this authentication flow?

I'm open to suggestions for error handling, security best practices, and scalability considerations.
